# How can I make the variables of my struct visible from all functions?

Tags: c++, database, variables, struct

So, my assignment in class was to make a C++ program that essentially makes a database with a number of options (adding to it, deleting entries, modifying, searching and listing). It has to be done specifically with arrays, not vectors or classes or whatever.

I decided to make a number of functions to handle each option, and have them all call each other. After extensive googling, I also decided to let a struct handle the declarations so I can use them in all functions without using :: marks. I specifically made everything depend on each other because the teacher hinted that we're going to have to do further work with it, so if I modify something, everything else changes to accommodate.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct va{

public:
    int i, j, k, l; //for possible loops or variables I only need for a very short time
    int id = 0;
    int name = id+1;
    // like 6 other ints I also declared here, including year2
    int achi = year2+1;
    //The above is for easier identification of pro[whatever][needed data]. The +1 method is to allow for easier editing later.

    int size = 20, row = 0; //This is important for addition
    string searchterm = ""; //this is for searching

public:
    int main();
    void MainMenu();
    void Addition();
    void Deletion();
    void Search();
    void Modify();
    void List();
};

void MainMenu();
void Addition();
void Deletion();
void Search();
void Modify();
void List(); 
//I just find it neater to make side functions after the main one.

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");


    const int column = achi;
    const int initsize = size; //These two are so I can edit the size of the array from the struct directly
    string pro[initsize][column]; //This creates the array that's the actual database

    cout << endl << "Welcome to the League of Legends Pro Players database!" << endl << endl;
    cout << endl << "Please, use the menu to access its functions.";

    MainMenu();

    cout << endl;
    return 0; 
}

void MainMenu()
{
    cout << endl << "Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << endl << "1: add an entry to the database.";
    cout << endl << "2: delete an existing entry from the database.";
    cout << endl << "3: search for an existing entry in the database.";
    cout << endl << "4: modify an existing entry.";
    cout << endl << "5: list all existing entries." << endl;

    cin  >> i;

    switch(i)
    {
        case 1: Addition();
        case 2: Deletion();
        case 3: Search();
        case 4: Modify();
        case 5: List();
    }
}
```

(I haven't written the actual functions for options yet.) However, when I tried to run it, I was told 'achi' wasn't declared in main, although I made everything public just so I won't run into this error. How could I make main "see" the struct and its variables?

Comment: `achi` is a member of your struct, ie you need an instance of that struct before you can access its members

Comment: *"int i, j, k, l; //for possible loops or variables I only need for a very short time"*, so prefer local variables.

Comment: Note that your class functions and functions with the same name in global scope are *different* functions, eg. `main()` in `va` is not the `main()` where your program executes.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Gosh .. there's a fair bit to question in what's written here.
 You have member functions in the struct (a struct is essentially a class, with default public access) - so you have two declarations for each function. Is this intended? Also, when you declare a struct, you're defining a conceptual entity. But to use it, you need to create an instance of it. Everything defined inside the struct belongs to the instance of the struct (assuming you have one.) I think there's some design questions regarding how C++ works that need to be ironed out before you're going to make much headway I'm afraid.

Comment: Another question to worry about - "..specifically with arrays, .. not classes..' - this is a bit concerning. Do you mean, you can't write new classes? (A struct is a class anyway) - or that you can't use existing classes, e.g. the STL?

Comment: Why are you declaring a `main()` function in your `struct`?

Comment: @Rags It is a school assignment, I guess he restricted us to using arrays for the database to have us practice it. *shrug* One of the reasons I want to use a class instead of global modifiers is to spite him. I technically did nothing wrong, the database is still arrays... He never said we can't include classes period.

Answer (score 0):

You have only defined a type, you don't have an values of that type. You have also declared but not defined a number of member functions, and then declared (and presumably defined, tho many are not shown) free functions with the same names.

When providing out-of-class definitions of member functions of `struct va`, you need to use `va::` to *qualify* the names of the members, to distinguish them from anything else with the same name. If this were not the case, then all the good names would be used up by members of classes in the standard library.

It's also good practice to declare variables at the narrowest possible location. Don't clutter the data members of `va` with things that can be local to it's member functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

struct va {
    static constexpr int size = 20;
    static constexpr int column = ???;
    std::string pro[size][column];

    void MainMenu();
    void Addition();
    void Deletion();
    void Search();
    void Modify();
    void List();
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    va instance;
    cout << endl << "Welcome to the League of Legends Pro Players database!" << endl << endl;
    cout << endl << "Please, use the menu to access its functions.";

    instance.MainMenu();

    cout << endl;
    return 0; 
}

void va::MainMenu()
{
    cout << endl << "Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << endl << "1: add an entry to the database.";
    cout << endl << "2: delete an existing entry from the database.";
    cout << endl << "3: search for an existing entry in the database.";
    cout << endl << "4: modify an existing entry.";
    cout << endl << "5: list all existing entries." << endl;

    int i;
    cin >> i;

    switch(i)
    {
        case 1: Addition();
        case 2: Deletion();
        case 3: Search();
        case 4: Modify();
        case 5: List();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to make a struct specifically to make global variables without having to use ::variablename. For example, id, name etc. are actually the numbers of columns, they are specifically defined outside of every function and dependant on each other because at a later point I will have to change the structure, and this would in theory allow me to just edit the struct and the entire program would reflect the change. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: @Vievin You can, and `pro` is visible in `::va::MainMenu`. But that is a **different function** to `::MainMenu` (namespace scoping included for emphasis)

Comment: @Vievin Avoid global variables. Reduce the scope of entities to the minimum possible - that way they have the minimum impact when you change things (and they don't pollute namespaces they shouldn't be, and other benefits.)

Comment: @Vievin Note that I have *removed* declarations of `::Addition` etc. In `va::MainMenu` the `Addition()` call will go to `va::Addition`

Comment: @Vievin What you want, I think, is to define a struct which represents the data structure you want to store. That definition can be global. Then have instances of that structure as your data objects - they all have the same type, and can have arrays of them (I would advise arrays of pointers to instances of them, rather than arrays of large object - various benefits, but probably outside the scope of your class.)